# Is it possible to cache variables using the {% cache %} tag?

Tags: cache

I would like to cache a variable and compare the cached variable with a parameter from the query string.

Is it possible to somehow cache a variable ?

```
{% cache using key "cacheId" %}
  {% set id = 1 %}
{% endcache %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twig [{% cache %}](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/cache) will only cache HTML output, not variables.  You could, however, store the value you want to check against in [a](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/lj-cookies) [cookie](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/cookies) or into the browser's local storage.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by using the set/endset tags to create a variable from the cached output:

```
{% set finalVariable %}
    {% cache %}
        {# heavy lifting (like queries) here #}
        {# output the contents of your variable here #}
        your output here or {{ yourOutputHere }}
    {% endcache %}
{% endset %}
```

In the above example the `finalVariable` will be set to the value of the cached content.

Or, in the case of the code example used in the question, something like this could be used:

```
{% set id %}{% spaceless %}
    {% cache using key "cacheId" %}
        1
    {% endcache %}
{% endspaceless %}{% endset %}
```

It's a very basic example that would probably never be used, but the `id` variable would be set to a string of `1` from the `cacheId` cache.

Note: The spaceless tags are just used to remove the whitespace.

Comment: You also need to use `{%-` instead of `{%` to remove whitespace inbetween the Twig tags.