# Problem with getHeadHtml(), getFootHtml() and caching

Tags: cache, getheadhtml

I have two problems when it comes to working with `getHeadHtml()` and `getFootHtml()`.

But first things first. Here's my setup:

This is my stripped down `_main.twig` layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ craft.locale }}">
<head>
    <!-- injected Css Files or Styles should go here -->
    {{ getHeadHtml() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scss/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    <!-- injected Js Files or Code should go here -->
    {{ getFootHtml() }}
</body>
</html>
```

This is my stripped down `_entry.twig` file:

```
{% extends "_layouts/_main" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for block in entry.cf_content_matrix %}
        {#
            Include all blocks
        #}
        {% include "_blocks/_block_" ~ block.type ignore missing %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the Matrix block that is causing the problems I have. 
Basically it is a jQuery slider plugin. I only want the JS and CSS files injected when this block is actually used. So I thought that using `includeCssFile`, `includeJsFile` and `includeJs` would be a perfect fit for this.

```
{% set images = block.images %}
<div id="screenshot-slider">
    {%- for image in images -%}
        <div><img src="{{ image.getUrl({ width: 680 }) }}" /></div>
    {%- endfor -%}
</div>

{% includeCssFile "/assets/javascripts/slick/slick.css" %}
{% includeCssFile "/assets/javascripts/slick/slick-theme.css" %}
{% includeJsFile "/assets/javascripts/slick/slick.min.js" %}
{% set owlJs %}
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#screenshot-slider").slick();
    });
{% endset %}
{% includeJs owlJs %}
```

OK. So far so good. It works rather well.

**Problem 1**

The `{{ getHeadHtml() }}` in the `_main.twig` file is somehow ignored. Instead of injecting the CSS files BEFORE my `styles.css` files, they are injected just before the `&lt;/head&gt;` tag. As if it wasn't there.

Anybody experienced this behaviour?

**Problem 2**

This concerns caching.

When I try to cache the content matrix the following way:

```
{% extends "_layouts/_main" %}

{% block content %}
    {% cache %}
        {% for block in entry.cf_content_matrix %}
            {#
                Include all blocks
            #}
            {% include "_blocks/_block_" ~ block.type ignore missing %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endcache %}
{% endblock %}
```

NOTHING get's injected. Neither the CSS files, nor the JS files.

Does anybody know why this is the case, and if there is a solution to it?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding Problem 1**

The Twig function `{{ getHeadHtml() }}` does only work with JS/CSS that are included before this tag. I had the same problem... you can find the answer/explanation of Brandon Kelly here: [getHeadHtml() not outputting CSS included with {% includeCss %}](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/getheadhtml-not-outputting-css-included-with-includecss)

**Regarding Problem 2**

The `{% cache %}` does only cache the output HTML, no variables (see [Is it possible to cache variables using the {% cache %} tag?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/is-it-possible-to-cache-variables-using-the-cache-tag/13338#13338)). As a workaround you could cache the `{{ getFootHtml() }}` as well: in the first request it process the complete Twig code and stores the `getFootHtml` content correct. With this solution, you need to delete the cache manually (or with the `onAfterSave` event) after (re)saving, and adding/deleting an entry that could affect the cache.
Note: This does not work with `{{ getHeadHtml() }}` (see Problem 1).